# There was an error generating the XML document when using Windows authentication pass-through

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0

I've set up a basic http WCF Service and my application in IIS is configured to use Windows Authentication.

The bindings therefore have the following security settings:

```
<security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" />
    <message clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
</security>
```

Each operation contract has the following attribute

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Authenticated = true)]
```

and the service class has the following attribute to allow asp compability

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = 
                              AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
```

The Windows authentication is passed to the WCF service properly, since I can see/generate the WSDL. However, when I call an operation in my WCF service i get the following error:

```
[FaultException`1: There was an error generating the XML document.]
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg,
                                                        IMessage retMsg) +4767763
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, 
                                                        Int32 type) +1725
   XXXX.Service() +0
   XXXX.Service() +329
   XXXX.Service() +747
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, 
                                                     Object t,EventArgs e) +25
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, 
                                    Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3048
```

It's not the first time i see the error **There was an error generating the XML document.**, I want to know what could be the reason for this? Does the Service send the data somewhat encrypted and the client doesn't understand it because it is miss-configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the you are not handling an exception/Fault in your code, you may want to ensure your serialising the error correctly, using the following

[http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pedram/archive/2008/01/25/wcf-error-handling-and-some-best-practices.aspx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/pedram/wcf-error-handling-and-some-best-practices)

I have also found a blog entry from Mike Taulty very good for enableing logging in WCF

[http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2005/12/15/5662.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20150915205532/http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2005/12/15/5662.aspx)

Hope this helps.

Comment: The error seem to be: `"The given assembly name or codebase, 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll', was invalid."` even though the file is there. strage.

Comment: it maybe that your web.config and your reference DLL may differ
in the 

<system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" strict="false" explicit="true">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly=" 

Section

Comment: I actually don't have an assemblies section in the web.config for the service.. hm

Comment: last thought is that you maybe caching, a compiled version of the DLL, try deleting the files from the following location

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files

Do a Solution Clean and Rebuild.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you've saved me a lot of headace! :)